# Learning R and Perl

Tags: perl, r, statistics

Can anybody help me with any good tutorial on Statistics::R module please? In the process of learning R perl, I used some code from web, but it is not working? This was an example where correlation could be estimated using statistics::R. But some how, it is not working for me, and i would be very thankful, if one of the experts can help me learn the underlying concepts. Any help will be highly appreciated?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#!/usr/lib/site/Perl/Statistics/R
#use Statistics::R;
#my $R = Statistics::R->new();
#$R->startR;
#$R->start_sharedR;
#@prob1=(0.05,0.03,0.08,0.01);
#@prob2=(0.08,0.05,0.03,0.15);
#$R->send('PROB1<-c("@prob1")');
#$R->send('PROB2<-c("@prob2")');
#$R->send('cor(PROB1,PROB2)');
#print $R->send() ;
#my $ret = $R->read;
#print "\$ret : $ret\n";
```

Comment: **every** line starts with `#`, is this what you intended? Or is it an attempt at some kind of *formatting*

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [Penn University's Introductory Course on R](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/index.html).

The ggplot chapter alone is worth reading - I found ggplot very confusing but this is a great explanation.